# Why is dashboard created using Dash not working?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I'm trying to create a Dashboard using Dash, a python package. It is either taking too much of time to execute or throws an error saying "error in loading dependencies".

I'm running it on Jupyter notebook on IE browser.

Could anyone explain me, where I'm going wrong?
Thanks all in advance.

I've tried running a sample code from "https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/learn-build-dash-python"

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd     
df= pd.read_excel("https://github.com/chris1610/pbpython/blob/master/data/salesfnnel.xlsx?raw=True")
mgr_options = df["Manager"].unique()

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H2("Sales Funnel Report"),
    html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id="Manager",
            options=[{
                'label': i,
                'value': i
            } for i in mgr_options],
            value='All Managers'),
    ],
    style={'width': '25%',
           'display': 'inline-block'}),
dcc.Graph(id='funnel-graph'),
])


@app.callback(
dash.dependencies.Output('funnel-graph', 'figure'),
[dash.dependencies.Input('Manager', 'value')])
def update_graph(Manager):
    if Manager == "All Managers":
        df_plot = df.copy()
    else:
        df_plot = df[df['Manager'] == Manager]

    pv = pd.pivot_table(
        df_plot,
        index=['Name'],
        columns=["Status"],
        values=['Quantity'],
        aggfunc=sum,
        fill_value=0)

    trace1 = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[('Quantity', 'declined')], name='Declined')
    trace2 = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[('Quantity', 'pending')], name='Pending')
    trace3 = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[('Quantity', 'presented')], name='Presented')
    trace4 = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[('Quantity', 'won')], name='Won')

    return {
        'data': [trace1, trace2, trace3, trace4],
        'layout':
        go.Layout(
            title='Customer Order Status for {}'.format(Manager),
            barmode='stack')
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader = False)
```

Error in loading dependencies.

Comment: I am not sure your code is correct or not but there is an indentation error when you define a function. Except that, I got 404 error for loading `.xlsx` file.

Comment: Thanks.Yeah I just noticed the indentation. But I'm able to read the excel file.

Comment: Please, provide the error you get.